# UWP Stretch GridView

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

How to stretch GridViewItem horizontaly? Trying to set property `HorizontalContentAlignment` or style property in `ItemContainerStyle`. This does not help.

[image: App example image]

Here is a code:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Banks}" SelectionMode="None" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </Style>
                </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Bank">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0" />

                            <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Departments}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsItemClickEnabled="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                                <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Department">
                                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />

                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding USD.Date}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>

                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding USD.Sell}" Grid.Column="2" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding USD.Buy}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            </GridView>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
```

Answer (score 6):

By default,`GridView` uses [`ItemsWrapGrid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemswrapgrid.aspx) as the panel to position and arrange `GridViewItem`, you can find this from **Live Visual Tree**:
[image]

Although you've set `HorizontalContentAlignment` or `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch` for `GridViewItem`, but the size of `GridViewItem` is limited by `ItemsWrapGrid`.

> `ItemsWrapGrid` positions child elements sequentially from left to right or top to bottom in an `ItemsControl` that shows multiple items. When elements extend beyond the container edge, elements are positioned in the next row or column.

So in `ItemsWrapGrid`, items won't be stretched.

If you want to stretch `GridViewItem` horizontaly, we can use `ItemsStackPanel` instead of `ItemsWrapGrid` like following:

In `Resources`, add a `ItemsPanelTemplate` with `ItemsStackPanel`:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="MyItemsPanelTemplate">
        <ItemsStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

Then use this template in `GridView`:

```
<GridView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
          ItemsPanel="{StaticResource MyItemsPanelTemplate}"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind Banks}"
          SelectionMode="None">
    ...
        <GridView Grid.Row="1"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
              ItemsPanel="{StaticResource MyItemsPanelTemplate}"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind Departments}">
        ...
        </GridView>
    ...
</GridView>
```

Or we can use `ListView` instead of `GridView` as `ListView`'s default `ItemsPanel` is `ItemsStackPanel`.

[image]