# grid inside gridview doesn't fill up the whole width

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I've been trying this for hours and this is supposed to be very basic but I'm having a hard time figure this out and I can't find any examples of this or solutions online. I am trying to do a grid layout bound to a list of items. I am using a Gridview which encompasses a grid. I can't get it to fill out the entire width. It only takes up half the window. If I pull the grid out of the GridView, it works fine and expands to the full window, so I know that it's a problem with GridView. Below is my code:

```
   <Page.Resources>
    <local:BoolToStringConverter x:Key="BoolToStringConverter" FalseValue="No" TrueValue="Yes" />
    <helpers:TimActivityTypeToStringConverter x:Key="TimActivityTypeToStringConverter" />
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:TimActivity" x:Key="TimDataTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind Path=Type, Converter={StaticResource TimActivityTypeToStringConverter}}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind StartTime}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{x:Bind EndTime}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{x:Bind From}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{x:Bind To}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Text="{x:Bind Comment}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="6" Text="{x:Bind Path=Chargeable, Converter={StaticResource BoolToStringConverter}}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Activities}" 
              IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
              ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TimDataTemplate}">
    </GridView>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just want to extend the gridview, then you can change Gridview's default `ItemsPanel` to use `ItemsStackPanel` instead of `ItemsWrapGrid` [as this solution provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35451090/7418444)

```
<GridView ... >
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

but your content will look like this instead.

[image: Preview of the code]
Based on your code, I'm guessing you don't want it to be aligned like that. Just add this line will also fix the problem above

```
<GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

[image: Preview of the code]

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, what you are talking about is the default behaviour of `ListViewItem` and `GridViewItem`.

You can modify it just by applying a simple `Style` to the `GridView`:

```
<GridView.Style>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
         <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</GridView.Style>
```

Best regards